# Maximum Likelihood Function for computing AIC of LS regression models

Tags: maximum-likelihood, least-squares, model-selection, likelihood, aic

In Burnham & Anderson: Model Selection and Multimodel Inference (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97636), the author states that the likelihood function used in the Akaike information criterion can be replaced with this:

In case the error variance is constant and normally distributed:
\begin{equation*}
 AIC = n*\log(\hat{\sigma}^2)+2*K
\end{equation*}
In which sigma^2 hat is the MLE of the variance of the residuals:
\begin{equation*}
 \hat{\sigma}^2=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\hat{\epsilon_i}^2
\end{equation*}
epsilon hat squared are the residuals of a certain model used for linear regression. Can someone help me understand how the MLE for the variance of the residuals can replace the negatively signed maximum log likelihood function of the usual AIC criterion. Instead of doing this, I would have put in the simulated data into an multiplication of normal distributions.

Comment: The specific problem you seem to be referring to is that of normally distributed  data with unknown mean and variance. In that case $2\log \hat L = -\sum_i \hat \epsilon_i^2 / 2\hat \sigma^2  - n\log \hat \sigma^2$. The first term is a constant due to relation you wrote, so it can be ignored when comparing models which all have the same constant.

Comment: Thanks @J.Delaney! This post actually helped me a lot to understand it: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/483801/log-likelihood-computation-for-aic-bic?rq=1
When I assume equal normal distribution, like you mentioned, this refers to the error terms at each individual datapoint, right? Because my solution vector y obviously is distributed very differently.

Comment: @J.Delaney but we can also say that
\begin{equation*}
 \sigma^2 = RSS/n
\end{equation*}
so that this eq can be simplified (like in the solution at this link above):
\begin{equation*}
2*\log(\hat{L})=const. - n*\log(RSS)
\end{equation*}
Or am I missing something there?

Comment: Yes those are equivalent