# To the likelihood of what does the loglikelihood in AIC, BIC refer?

Tags: likelihood, aic, model-comparison, bic

Both Akaike's information criterion and Bayesian information criterion are calculated from the loglikelihood, eg AIC= -2 log-likelihood +2k.

To the likelihood of what does it refer to? The likelihood of 1) the model that I fit to the data or of 2) the distribution I draw my data from at each point? So, with 2) I mean, if I have data points at {(x_i,y_i)} and take some fixed x the distribution for drawing y.

Or phrased with an example: If I have some data, each point with an gaussian error, to which I fit an exponential function, do I compute the log-likelihood of the gaussian or of the exponential function?

Edit: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564584/maximum-likelihood-function-for-computing-aic-of-ls-regression-models?noredirect=1&lq=1) the question also came up in the comments, but wasn't answered

Comment: They refer to the likelihood function of assumed model.

Comment: Is there then a way to take known uncertainties in the data into account?

Comment: Why do they talk then of 'gaussian error' eg here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/483801/log-likelihood-computation-for-aic-bic?rq=1 ?